# Images jump 5 pixels on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two clickable images inside a `div`. They jump 3-6 pixels when clicked. If I set it to fixed or absolute it doesn't jump but floating the elements together in one `div` is good formatting.

```
 <div class="buttons">
     <a onclick="$('.positionHelper').scrollTo( {top:'-=100px', left:'0'}, 800 );" href="#">
         <img src="images/up.png" />
     </a>
     <a onclick="$('.positionHelper').scrollTo( {top:'+=100px', left:'0'}, 800 );" href="#">
         <img src="images/down.png" />
     </a>
 </div>

.buttons {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -34px;
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can you  host it on jsfiddle?

Comment: What is actually your question?

Comment: What do you mean "jump"? Do you mean the images change position in relation to other elements on the page? Given that the code associated with your `a` tags is trying to change the scroll position for element(s) not shown in your question could that be part of the problem? Is the div you show inside the one that those links are scrolling?

Comment: what i mean by jump is the visually move up 4 pixils, the code in firebug does not show anything that changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the line-height of .buttons to 0.